Candle opacity based on volume average and current volume
Basically I am trying to make an indicator if the volume is above average then the candlestick is 100% opacity but if the volume is below average the candlestick the opacity is 50%. I am stuck as I can't seem to change the opacity of the bar
//@version=5
indicator("Bar Opacity Based on Volume", overlay=true)

avgVolume = ta.sma(volume, 60)

volumeAboveAvg = volume > avgVolume

currentColor = color.new(color.blue, 100)

barcolor(color.new(currentColor, volumeAboveAvg ? 0 : 100))

This is what I have so far it changes the bar color to blue. I'm also not sure how to make the whole bar change color it's just the body

For transp, possible values are 0 (not transparent) to 100 (invisible).
Try this:
barcolor(color.new(currentColor, volumeAboveAvg ? 50 : 0))


yeah that's better, thanks :)
